# cx_Oracle backward compatible?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

On my server installed cx_Oracle of 5.3 version.

I want to update in to 6 version. But I'm afraid that python scripts, which are now on the server, stop working with the new version.

cx_Oracle backward compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an idea of what's changed and might affect your app, review the release notes at http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/python-cx_oracle-6-production-release

The fundamental software rule when upgrading versions is to test it with your application.